# How to save each input without resaving previous inputs each time

Tags: java

In trying to save input from a user to file without overwriting the previous input, Ive found that after each time a new entry is saved and the program is exited, the next time the program is run and I view the textfile, the previous data to the last entry has repeated itself or I should say saved again on top of the last file save. Can anyone see why the program is not saving the last file only and then just adding itself to the previous files? I would appreciate any help, its probably really simple, but cant see what the problem is myself, thank you.

Below is the code I have to save the input

```
try {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("EventsList.txt", true);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

    for (Events e : event) {
        pw.println(Integer.toString(e.getRefNo()));
        pw.println(e.getDate());
        pw.println(e.getArtist());
        pw.println(e.getVenue());
        pw.println(e.getCity());
        pw.println(Double.toString(e.getTicketCost()));
        pw.println(Integer.toString(e.getQuantity()));

    }

    pw.close(); // close output stream

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Error!");
}

break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass true as a second argument to PrintWriter to turn on "append" mode.

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw, true);
```

Comment: Second argument is "autoFlash", not "append".

Comment: tried this but when i exit program after saving a new entry and then rerun the program, the file has saved the new entry but has also still saved the previous entries again.

Comment: Had a look again, it was true to turn on append mode in the second argument as you said spieriz, but I also needed to remove true from the filewriter as this was causing the problem.  Thanks guys for all the help.